# SSRS email subscription sending the old version of the report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, ssrs-2012

I have a ssrs report with email subscription which excel attachment every morning to a list of email addresses. The report is sending 2 emails everyday now after i updated the report and redeployed it to the report server. I have tried deleting the subscription and creating new one, deleting the report and redeploying with the new report name but neither of these is helpful. The report caching property is set to use the recent data. checked at the report server catalog where there is only the new version of the report. Any idea why it's sending email attachment with old version of the report although the there is no subscription available.
I am using VS 2013

Comment: If you delete the SSRS report and do not replace it, what happens? Based on your symptoms, it could be that you're not touching the actual report that is used in the email.

Comment: I have depolyed the report again with the different name and now i am getting 2 email attachments with old and new version of reports

Comment: If you don't deploy it again, you will likely only get the old one, right? To me, that means you're not editing the right report and there is a similarly named report maybe in a different directory that is running.

Comment: Thanks. Found out the report was in the development server with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking there is a copy of the report somewhere.. possibly hidden that is sending out the subscription.

Run the following against your report server

```
SELECT
sj.[name] AS [Job Name],
rs.SubscriptionID,
c.[Name] AS [Report Name],
c.[Path],
su.Description


FROM msdb..sysjobs AS sj 

INNER JOIN ReportServer..ReportSchedule AS rs
ON sj.[name] = CAST(rs.ScheduleID AS NVARCHAR(128)) 

INNER JOIN ReportServer..Subscriptions AS su
ON rs.SubscriptionID = su.SubscriptionID

INNER JOIN ReportServer..[Catalog] c
ON su.Report_OID = c.ItemID

where c.[Name]  like '%your report name here%'
```

you should get all associated subscriptions for the report.

user the job name and plug that into the following code and execute it and see what arrives. You may find there is a hidden report that is running the subscription. I've had that happen to me before!

```
USE [msdb]
EXEC sp_start_job @job_name = '05FC75D8-9F73-424E-A078-1F78A6AC3262'
 --enter the job name from the above query into this query to run the job :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the report in the SSRS folder, click the drop down and choose manage. Then go to processing options and choose: Always run this report with the most recent data. And also choose do not cache temporary copies of this report.